# How does the for loop operate exactly?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

```
for (let counter = 3; counter >= 0 ; counter--){
  console.log(counter);
}
```

I am still learning and I am making a simple for loop that logs the numbers 3 2 1 0 and I am having a difficulty understanding why do I have to set the stopping condition (counter >= 0) which comes after the initialization ( `let counter = 3`) and not ( `counter > 0` ) to get the right answer.
isn’t the number 1 is bigger than 0 and when checked against the stopping condition should evaluate to true?
also why when I set the stopping condition to  `counter = 0` it doesn't log anything?

Comment: the code `counter = 0` affect zero to counter. it is not a test. it return zero, which is the value of `false`

Comment: In your case you could replace the condition counter >= 0 by counter > -1 .

Comment: @Barmar when I was introduced to the for loop on (codecademy) it was stated clearly that the second expression (the you are referring to ) is a stopping condition, now you are telling me that is the wrong and it's a continuing condition? is that what you are trying to say?

Answer (score 1):

A `for` loop in the form

```
for (initialization; condition; increment) {
    body
}
```

is roughly<sup>*</sup> equivalent to the `while` loop:

```
initialization;
while (condition) {
    body;
    increment;
}
```

If you change the condition to `counter == 0` (I'm assuming `=` was a typo in the question, not the actual code), the `while` condition fails the first time, because `3 == 0` is not true. So the body is never executed and the loop stops immediately.

<sub>[*] I say "roughly" because there's a difference related to variable scope if `let` is used to declare the variable in the initialization clause.</sub>

Comment: Ok that I understand what I don't understand is why when I set the condition to `counter < 0` and not to `counter <= 0` it logs the zero is not the the value 1 is bigger than 0 and the incremented result should be logged to the console also why when I set the value of the condition to something `counter = 11` it keeps on logging the number 11 indefinitely?

Comment: If `counter == 3`, then `counter < 0` and `counter <= 0` are not true. So the `while` loop stops immediately.

Comment: I am not exposed yet to the while loop I was asking about the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Let's break down your code:

```
for (let counter = 3; counter >= 0 ; counter--){
  console.log(counter);
}
```

We need a initiator for starting a loop. So we started with counter from 3. Then we gave it an iteration condition that if counter is less than or equals zero the loop will iterate and on each move it will decrease the counter number by one. The (--) means decrement.
Now come to your problem. (>=) will continue the loop on 0 and only using (>) will stop it before zero. This is the difference. You can change it and see what happens.
`counter = 0`  you can't set a condition like this. A condition must have two operators eg. (==)(!=)(>=)(<=). So the use is invalid. We use this format to declare a new value into variable.

Answer (score 0):

Breaking it down into three parts:
First part:
`counter=3`
Second part:
`counter>=0`
Third part:
`counter--`

For the first part: 
It is the initialisation, which sets the variable `counter` to 3.
For the second part:
It is the condition. It will stop the loop when the condition is false.
The condition consists of an `operator`.
For the operator, `>=` means bigger than or equal. `==` means equal

**Note that `=` isn't a comparison operator. It means 'counter is 0'.**
For the third part:
It is the operation.
It will run every iteration, or cycle.
`--` means 'decrease by 1'